# Can I travel to Kuwait on a employment visa with old passport number?

Tags: visas, kuwait

I have a Kuwait employment visa, with my old passport number. But as the old passport has ECR on it I got a new passport with a new passport number with ECNR. Can I travel with the same visa or do I have to obtain a new visa with my new passport number?

Answer (score -2):

I assume your old passport has been canceled. In that case, you will have to obtain a new visa to enter the country again.

Comment: This is almost certainly incorrect.

Comment: I saw a query similar to that of mine,as it was stated in that to take both our passports I certainly didn't find it as a solution when I approached the agency.